# Comprehending Corr heatmap from multiple trials of investment strategy (Paper)

Tags: backtesting, quants, strategy, data-mining

Can someone please explain the heatmap of Corr from backtests in this research paper ?
*[A Data Science Solution to the Multiple-Testing Crisis in Financial Research -  Lopez De Prado (2019)](https://images.aqr.com/-/media/AQR/Documents/Journal-Articles/JFDS_Winter2019_A-Data-Science-Solution-to-Multiple-Testing-Crisis---Lopez_de_Prado.pdf)* - (Exhibit #3 on Page 3)

It is not clear how the Index vs Strategy correlation data points from 6,385 trials are represented/ordered in the Heat map.

The following explanation in the paper did not help much :
***"As is customary in machine learning applications, the main diagonal crosses the Cartesian product from the bottom left to the top right."***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row/column of the heatmap is a trial. The matrix is the correlations between the different strategy trial returns, not the index vs strategy scatter plot.

The cluster analysis on the next page builds upon this.